# How can I disable Zathura's statusbar by default?

Tags: linux, terminal, pdf, zathura

I'd like to hide the statusbar by default when opening Zathura (Which is normally done with ***^n***)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to UNIX & Linux at Stack Exchange. Please consider reviewing the [tour] and the help-center topic [How to ask a good question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), then updating your question with specific details regarding what you have already tried and any specific errors you have encountered.

Comment: Zathura's latest version does not provide that feature from the command line: https://git.pwmt.org/pwmt/zathura/blob/master/doc/man/_options.txt
You will have to recompile zathura if you want that behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Add this line in your config (~/.config/zathura/zathurarc):

```
set guioptions ""
```